# How can I use find_withtag without knowing the last few characters at the end of the tag name?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have objects on a canvas (using Tkinker) representing pieces of 'food'. I want to remove all instances of that object, but their tags all include a number at the end (Food0, Food1, Food2 ect). How can I remove all objects of that class type without knowing what number is at the end of its tag?

```
food_tags = canvas.find_withtag('Food*') 
             # Find all tags starting with 'Food'
print(food_tags)
for tag in food_tags:
    print(tag)
    canvas.delete(tag)
```

Object names are:
Food0
Food1
Food2
Food3
ect.

Canvas.find_withtag('Food*') returns an empty list, so the for loop is never entered.

Comment: Please use [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for your posts.

Comment: How about splitting the tag into two?#

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a pattern with `find_withtag`. However, items can have more than one tag. What I recommend is to give each item the unique tag like you're doing now, and then an additional tag representing a group. For example, you can do `tags=("Food1", "Food")`. You can then search for `Food` and it will find all items with that tag.

For the canonical description of what you can use to reference items in a canvas method, see [Item IDs and Tags](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M16) in the official tk documentation.

Here is an example that creates two groups of objects: Food items and Music items:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="bisque", width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(1,11):
    canvas.create_text(10, i*20, text=f"Food{i}", anchor="nw", tags=(f"Food{i}", "Food"))

for i in range(1,11):
    canvas.create_text(100, i*20, text=f"Music{i}", anchor="nw", tags=(f"Music{i}", "Music"))

assert(canvas.find_withtag("Food") == (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
assert(canvas.find_withtag("Music") == (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20))

root.mainloop()
```